# Separating output of integers with commas in java

Tags: java

I have to write a program that finds primes between two user inputted numbers. The only problem I'm having is that the output has one extra comma than it needs. How would I go about fixing this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Primes {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int start = sc.nextInt();
    int end = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i =start; i <= end; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            System.out.printf("%d,", i);
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i =2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
     }
     return true;
  }
}
```

Input: `1 10`

Output: `2,3,4,5,7,9,`

Comment: Would you know ahead of time which is the last prime in the range?

Comment: You can't print a comma after the integer, because you don't know at that point whether there will be another integer following.  Instead, print the comma _before_ the integer, and don't do it the first time.  You might need a `boolean` to keep track of whether it's the first time.

Comment: My comment was directed to the now deleted comment from shmosel, not to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use a StringJoiner is more apropriate in this case:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Primes {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int start = sc.nextInt();
    int end = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i =start; i <= end; i++) {

        if (isPrime(i)) {
            joiner.add(Integer.toString(i));
        }

    }

    System.out.println(joiner.toString());
}
```

without StringJoiner :

```
public class Primes {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    String separator = "";

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int start = sc.nextInt();
    int end = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i =start; i <= end; i++) {

        if (isPrime(i)) {
            System.out.printf(separator + "%d", i);

            separator = ",";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about StringJoiner.  Very useful.

Comment: Yes it is, it was introduced since java 8.

Comment: this works, but how would I do it without StringJoiner? I'm in a beginner Java class and we haven't learned that yet.

Comment: @MouadELFakir Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit of a different approach, using streams:

```
String output = IntStream.rangeClosed(start, end)
        .filter(Primes::isPrime)
        .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

System.out.println(output);
```