The output for my proper divisors is incorrect it should be The proper divisors of 25 are: {1, 5, }. The proper divisors of 28 are: {1, 2, 4, 7, 14}
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GreatestCF {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        checkAmicableNumbers(sc);
    }

    // 9
    public static void checkAmicableNumbers(Scanner sc) {
        System.out.println("Enter the first number:");
        int num1 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the second number:");
        int num2 = sc.nextInt();
        factorPairs2(num1);
        factorPairs2(num2);

        if (areAmicable(num1, num2)) {
            System.out.println("The numbers "+num1+ "and "+num2+" are amicable numbers!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The numbers "+num1+ " and "+num2+" are not amicable numbers!");
        }
    }

    public static boolean areAmicable(int num1, int num2) {
        return (sumOfProperDivisors(num1) == num2 && sumOfProperDivisors(num2) == num1);
    }

    public static int sumOfProperDivisors(int num) {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < num / 2; i++) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }

        return sum;
    }

    public static void factorPairs2(int n) {
        System.out.print("The proper divisors of "+n+" are: {");
        for (int i = 1; i <= n / 2; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                System.out.print(i);
                if (i != n / 2) {
                    System.out.print(", ");
                } 
            }
        }
    
        System.out.print("}.\n");
    }
}

My output for the  proper divisors is adding an extra comma at the end before the closing curly bracket , and I am having trouble figuring out how to fix it . I cannot use list in the code as it has not been discussed in the class yet.

Well you know that 1 is always a factor so you could output that and then prepend the comma each time there's a new factor (starting with two in the loop.)

First don't directly print everything, store it in a String variable. Second use this trick myResult = ""; at the start of the loop do if ( myString != "" ) {myString += ", ";} and then concatenate your divisors.

Welcome to stackoverflow. Always try to use a descriptive summary as title; don't cram all the details in the title. That's for the body of the question; see [ask]. Also try to make a [mcve]. If your problem is about printing a series of values, we don't really need the code that calculates the values.

instead of testing for i != n / 2, test for i > 1 to print the comma, and print it before printing the number -- i != n / 2 will not work for odd numbers since the last factor is not n / 2

Have you searched to see if others have had this problem before? What about this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194898/separating-output-of-integers-with-commas-in-java ?

Work with a sep string. Set it initially to "" and print it before the number. Then, if you find a divisor, change it to ", ". On subsequent divisors (if there are any), it will print the comma "after" the previous number.
public static void factorPairs2(int n) {   
    String sep = "";

    System.out.print("The proper divisors of "+n+" are: {");
    for (int i = 1; i <= n / 2; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            System.out.print(sep);
            System.out.print(i);
            sep = ", ";
        }
    }
    System.out.println("}.");
}


Just a note, this single assignment is one instruction. Using an if to decide whether to use a comma or not has more overhead than just assigning all the time.
